# Getting position of span or div text

Tags: javascript, html

Straight to the point; I'm trying to get a position of a word. I use `<a id='' rel=''>` tags to add some magic with it.

JavaScript:

```
   function getPosition(element) 
   {
      var xPosition = 0;
      var yPosition = 0;

      while(element) 
      {
          xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
          yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
          element = element.offsetParent;
      }
      return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
   }
```

HTML part inside JavaScript:

```
var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
var parentPos = getPosition(link[i]);
tooltip.setAttribute('class', 'object-tooltip');
tooltip.style.border = "solid 1px red";
tooltip.style.color = "black";
tooltip.style.position = "fixed";
tooltip.style.left = parentPos.x+"px";
tooltip.style.padding = "10px";
tooltip.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
tooltip.style.textDecoration = "none";
tooltip.innerHTML = "<p> test </p>";
```

I was very very tired when I wrote this all. Next morning after douzens cups of coffee I wondered why the positioning is not functioning as it should. Then I noticed the `getPosition()` is getting position of currect element. Problem is that the test link is in a div block, and this div block has like six different parents. Plus, I'm planning to put these links to all the other div blocks as well.

So, I want the `getPosition()` to get position of the link in the whole site, not just the position in the current element. What I am trying to do here is to get a little box when hovering a link. The hovering part itself works fine, but the box positioning is not working. I just can't figure it out by myself :-/

Also, if you want more details or anything, feel free to ask!

UPDATE:

JSFiddle with UJC's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/1/

The tooltip should get cursor's position and go below the cursor.

Comment: It will be nice if you can add a sample on jsfiddle.

Comment: Here you go!
http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(not sure this helps - but just in case)

If the problem you're trying to solve is similar to having a tooltip hover effect, here's a JSFiddle that shows how to do that based on the position of the mouse (rather than the position of the element the mouse is hovering over):

- Using `Event.clientX` and `Event.clientY`

  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VR4Tg/)

..hope this might be helpful (-!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I quickly googled about clientX variable it seems to be the right answer. Also your JSFiddle looks to be what I am looking for. You're right, I'm trying to get the position of the cursor. I never actually tried to google for like "get the position of your cursor", only tried to google for position of the element. That just sounded more reasonable to me. When something is really frustrating you, the problem can really be very simple when someone else takes a look at it hehe.

I'm currently at work, but I will let you know later did this solve the problem :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get into my website files and I created sample to  JSFiddle with your clientX variable. It's still not working correctly :-/ http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/1/

Comment: I've updated your JSFiddle. Have a look: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/2/)


2 main differences: 1) clientX is a property of the Event object (not the link), so I've updated the code so that the function accepts an Event (passed automatically by the browser), and extracted the 'rel' attribute from `event.target` into `str`.

2) The CSS `left` property needs to be explicitly set as `px` units (so added a `+'px'` to that. Hope this helps (-!

Comment: Thank you so much UJC! Now it's working as it should. But I need to trouble you once more. This tooltip thingy is not working correctly with images :-/. I updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/4/

Comment: No problem - happy to help. The problem is that the target of the event is always going to be the element that the mouse actually hover over. So, assuming the nesting is always going to be just 1 level deep into the `<a>` link - a quick fix is to get the `rel` attribute from either the element it self (if it's a link) - OR from the `parentNode` (which should be a link in case of a single level nest). This is the only code change: `var str = event.target.rel || event.target.parentNode.rel;`. And here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/5/

Comment: Okay thank you again, now everything's as it should be. Dunno how to thank you enough!

Comment: I'm not sure do you get notifications from this anymore. Just incase I 'ping' you @ujc . But I need to ask you how to do this with "addEventListener", or "attachEvent" for IE, because I just realized I'm going to have more than 100 tooltips on my site. The code would just be so messy, plus pain in the ass to write all mouseover, mousemove and mouseout to each <a> function. It would be simpler just to do with addEventListener/attachEvent and then have only the classname in the <a> function. Sorry for bothering you, but I didn't want to create new thread for this :P

Comment: No bother mate (-!

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/KYt3D/12/

* I remove the 'getPosition' function since it's no longer needed. Also, since this script now adds code by dynamically searching for elements with class 'tooltip' - the elements needs to be on the page before the script runs. This is done by running the script on DOM ready, or just placing the script at the bottom of the page before the closing </body> tag (better for performance). Feel free to comment again if you need anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had problem with the javascript but it was my XML which is not making this code fully functioning. Without any XML (tested on JSFiddle) the tooltips works just fine. But with XML, tooltips won't even show up. So something is definitely wrong with the XML. I try by myself first to fix it, but if I can't get it to work, I will make a new comment here. Kinda odd though, tooltips work when I have XML but I'm not using 'addEventListener' (I set manually "onmouseover" etc for each <a> tags). But when I include your latest code (these events) tooltips won't load :-/

Comment: If you can put part of the XML you're trying in a JSFiddle I'll be happy to have a look.

Comment: Apparently addEventListener now looks like to work in this JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7g3dK/1/ I commented out XML part because it won't function at all on JSFiddle because I use XML to get data from mysql database with the rel attribute. So JSFiddle obviously won't find the file in the code so I commented out the XML part. But hey, try it out on your computer, or if you somehow can sort it in JSFiddle :P So this code works fine on my site without the addEventListener, and hardcoding the events into <a> tags. But with addEventListener it won't work.